# Обработка массива php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> array(21) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["bid_number"]=>
    string(5) "18564"
    ["cat"]=>
    string(3) "439"
    ["subcat"]=>
    string(3) "440"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "447"
    ["subtype"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product"]=>
    string(27) "Красный кирпич"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["percent"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["bid_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(30) "Тестовая заявка "
    ["delay"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["invoice"]=>
    string(10) "2147483647"
    ["project"]=>
    string(29) "Тестовый проект"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-15"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(25) "Новый коммент"
    ["delivery"]=>
    string(29) "Санкт-Петербург"
    ["region"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["adress"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=> array(21) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["bid_number"]=>
    string(5) "18564"
    ["cat"]=>
    string(3) "439"
    ["subcat"]=>
    string(3) "440"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "447"
    ["subtype"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product"]=>
    string(23) "Белый кирпич"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["percent"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["bid_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(30) "Тестовая заявка "
    ["delay"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["invoice"]=>
    string(10) "2147483647"
    ["project"]=>
    string(29) "Тестовый проект"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-15"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(25) "Новый коммент"
    ["delivery"]=>
    string(29) "Санкт-Петербург"
    ["region"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["adress"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=> array(21) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["bid_number"]=>
    string(5) "11564"
    ["cat"]=>
    string(3) "439"
    ["subcat"]=>
    string(3) "440"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "447"
    ["subtype"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product"]=>
    string(23) "Белый кирпич"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["percent"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["bid_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["name"]=>
    string(31) "Тестовая заявка 2"
    ["delay"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["invoice"]=>
    string(10) "2147483647"
    ["project"]=>
    string(29) "Тестовый проект"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-15"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(25) "Новый коммент"
    ["delivery"]=>
    string(29) "Санкт-Петербург"
    ["region"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["adress"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Нужно вывести сгруппировав по `bid_number`:

```
Заявка номер 18564 
Кирпич Красный 
Белый Кирпич
Заявка номер 11564
Белый кирпич
```

Из базы выборка таким кодом :

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT *
FROM bids_product
LEFT JOIN bids
ON ( bids.bid_number = bids_product.bid_number )');
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();

foreach($data as $_data) {
  $result[$_data['bid_number']][] = array(
       'product' => $_data['product'],
       'over_data' => $_data['over_data'],
          .....
  );
}

print_r($result);
```

Но если возможно то лучше хранить сущность заказа в одной таблице, а сущность айтимов в другой. Либо заюзать поле json для хранения вложеного массива как есть.

Comment: Получилось вот так, не удобной вариант, так как нужно вывести в итоге всю связанную с лотом информацию 18564
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "Красный кирпич"
  [1]=>
  string(29) "Санкт-Петербург"
  [2]=>
  string(23) "Белый кирпич"
  [3]=>
  string(29) "Санкт-Петербург"
}
11564
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "Белый кирпич"
  [1]=>
  string(29) "Санкт-Петербург"
}

Comment: И получается мне нужно еще  обратиться к некоторым значениям из корня массива. Как то так, заявка номер(регион,даты,продукты(тип, название, кол-во))

Comment: @Слава ответил выше закинь всё массив с нужными ключами

Comment: Закинул, но получается, что регион дублируется для каждого типа продукта.

Comment: Получилось вот так и как то не красиво.  $result[$_data['bid_number']]['0'] = $_data['region'];
 $result[$_data['bid_number']]['1'] = $_data['delivery'];
 $result[$_data['bid_number']]['2'] = $_data['delay'];
 $result[$_data['bid_number']]['3'] = $_data['date'];
$result[$_data['bid_number']][] = array("product" => array($_data['product'], $_data['quantity'], $_data['cost']));